# Powershell split items into text file into multiple variables

Tags: powershell, split, lines

I am trying to run a software script against my servers, to see exactly what software is installed and what version. I have the list of the servers stored in a text file "SystemList.txt" that is formatted like you see below.

```
SERVER001
SERVER002
SERVER003
SERVER004
```

I need to pull the server names out of the file and use them in my csv that I need to look like this: [image: Excel Sheet]

Here is the code:

```
$computers = Get-Content -path 
D:\Users\stephen.lyons.sa\Documents\SystemList\SystemList.txt

Foreach($computer in $computers)
{
$computer
$env:COMPUTERNAME
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* 
|Select-Object Displayname, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Out-
file \\txusocts002\d$\APSO\Steve\Test\$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, here. Please reformat your question to show the format of your server name file correctly, and provide an example of what you want the resulting CSV to look like.,

Comment: The "csv file" example is a report and not strictly a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but would this meet your CSV file need?

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion,Publisher,InstallDate |
    Export-Csv -Path my.csv
```

Comment: Sorry I think I may have left something out, I am not able to run the report against my entire list of servers. I can only run it against one right now

Comment: To run on another machine, `Invoke-Command` will probably be needed. How about taking another run at the code using `Invoke-Command`?